# DidReceiveWriteRequest not getting called in IOS BLE

Tags: ios, xcode5, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

I am trying to send a response from central to peripheral. The code was worked fine twice. Suddenly `didReceiveWriteRequest` is not getting called. I didn't make any changes even.The properties given at peripheral are CBCharacteristicsPropertyNotify | `CBCharacteristicsPropertyWriteWithResponse and CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite`. The permissions given are `CBAttributePermissionsWriteable | CBAttributePermissionsReadable`. At central I have given setNotifyValue=YES in `didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService` method. And this is how I try to write from central:

```
[peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:self.peripheralCharacteristicn type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

I can't find any mistakes in what I have done. For some reason, didReceiveWriteRequest is not getting called at Peripheral. Please advice.

Comment: same problem here!! no idea!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same problem.
Couple of things you can try:

1. From the central side, try changing the 'write to characteristic' API to with response / without response appropriately.
2. On the peripheral side (which is your iOS device), try using either of the 'didReceiveWrite':

i. [didReceiveWriteRequests](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanagerdelegate/1393315-peripheralmanager?language=objc)

ii. [didReceiveWrite](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanagerdelegate/1393315-peripheralmanager)

iii. didReceiveWriteRequest - Don't miss the singular 'Request' in the name. This one receives only one object of CBATTRequest, as opposed to an array of requests in case of the first API 'didReceiveWriteRequests'

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same issue - my **didReceiveWrite** callback wasn't being executed. My solution was not just implementing the ".write" CBCharacteristic property, but rather the ".writeWithoutResponse", as on my Central-side (which happens to be a Raspberry Pi running BluePy), my "write" request wasn't requiring a response.

The characteristic that works looks something like this:

```
        myChar1 = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: CBUUID(nsuuid: UUID(uuidString: MYUUID)), properties: [.writeWithoutResponse], value: nil, permissions: [.readable, .writeable])
```